# What's the best way to segment tenants and hostnames in DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

We have a B2B model where we host a portal in Azure for our small business customers' employees, partners, and customers.  This is currently working well for us in a node.js web app, but we'd like to move to Azure Functions for mass scale, and this is causing us to rethink the initial design.

Currently, every XHR request that comes in to the web app goes through this logic:

1. Retrieve the siteconfig document corresponding to the hostname
2. Retrieve the organization_id from the siteconfig document
3. Insert the organization_id into the WHERE clause of the query

We are using node-cache to store the siteconfig documents in memory, so retrieval times are still very fast, only the first time a hostname is requested do we run two queries in series.

As Azure Functions don't store state between requests or have cache, we won't be able to cache the hostname/organizationid relationship.  It also seems that if we run two DocumentDB queries in one Function for every request then our database costs will nearly double.

So my question is this - is there a good way to retrieve this information in a single query that can be loaded into a Azure Function?  In the old world of RDBMS I'd just use a join or maybe even a subquery like this:

```
SELECT c.name, c.price
FROM c
WHERE c.type = "product"
AND c.organization_id = 
  (SELECT d.organization_id FROM d WHERE d.hostname = @hostname)
```

Here are some sample documents below.  To be specific, when a request comes in to portal.xyz.com/api/products we want to return Widget A and Widget B using a single query but NOT Gadget as that belongs to a different company.

```
{
  id: "17500961",
  type: "organization",
  name: "XYZ inc."
}

{
  id: "34903332",
  type: "siteconfig",
  hostname: "portal.xyz.com",
  organizationid: "17500961"
}

{
  id: "86785057",
  type: "product",
  name: "Widget A",
  price: "9.99",
  organizationid: "17500961"
}

{
  id: "17979681",
  type: "product",
  name: "Widget B",
  price: "14.99",
  organizationid: "17500961"
}

{
  id: "24669887",
  type: "product",
  name: "Gadget",
  price: "899",
  organizationid: "31514620"
}
```

We don't want to depend on the organizationid coming in from the client in the data request, this provides internal security knowing that Company X can never retrieve data for any organization but their own, as determined on the server by the incoming request headers.

One solution that has gone through my mind is to add the hostname to every document, but that seems like an extreme amount of redundant/replicated data.

Would the DocumentDB experts care to weigh in on this and provide some guidance?

Comment: My first advice to you would be to implement it with two round trips and then  optimize to a local cache only after you validate that this is not performant or too expensive.

Comment: Are you saying that there is indeed no way to do this within a single query in DocumentDB?

Comment: You could use the approach that you propose, caching, or Fabios other suggestions below. However, those add complexity. All I'm saying is try the straight forward two round trips approach before you resort to adding that complexity.

Comment: I'm going to read between the lines here and assume you really meant to say "this is not possible in one query in DocumentDB so you should find another way."

Comment: That is what I'm implying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone might be able to provide additional options when it comes to Cosmos DB/DocumentDB, but here are some of the options you have from an Azure Functions perspective:

**1. Use authentication information to derive the Organization ID**

You haven't described how you're authenticating your users, but a very common approach would be to ensure things like your tenant ID (in your case, the organization ID) are present as a claim in a signed token that can be validated on the server. This completely eliminates the need for caching or the additional lookup after the token is issued.

**2. Use an external cache**

An external cache like [Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/) would allow you to maintain the state you need outside of your functions environment and would be accessible from your Function App instances as it scales. This offers great performance at a great value (you'd need to compare the costs to what you'd be paying for Document DB requests based on your load)

**3. Local static mapping**

*Use this option as a fallback only as it is not predictable and may change over time. The other 2 options are recommended over this*

You can maintain a local cache in your Function App environment to reduce the number of lookups. That cache would ensure those lookups don't happen per request, but per runtime instance instead, so as your Function App scales, new instances would not have that cache populated, but once the information is cached, subsequent requests hitting the same host would not need to fetch the organization information.
**You need to keep a close eye on the application behavior if you opt to use this solution, since, as mentioned above, it may vary and won't be as predictable**

I hope this helps.

Comment: can you elaborate on #1? In particular, how do you embed something in the token? and, How do you validate it?

Comment: Notes for Fabio's answer #3: 1) D:\HOME (environment variable %HOME%) is shared across all instances. D:\local\Temp (%TMP%) and D:\local\AppData (%APPDATA%) are not shared among instances. These are size limited depending. 2) To get a local cache for Azure Functions, I have used %TMP% and node-localstorage's JSONStorage class. 3) #2 adds complexity. So does my recommendations on #3, but much less. My philosophy is to do the simplest thing that works and so far, I haven't had to resort to something like an external Redis Cache so I believe it's actually preferable over #2 IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, this has a lot of great information.  The auth token could work, but I'd have to be careful as one end-user could have access to more than one of our customers' portals.  The Redis Cache looks awesome, and very cost effective.